# Inner matrix dimensions error must agree error when plotting

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm attempting to plot the function: f(x) = x * e^(x) * cos(x) from 0 to 2*pi. I've tried running:

```
x = 0:pi/100:2*pi;
y = x*exp(x)*cos(x)
```

However, every time I attempt to set y. Matlab throws me a 'Error using *' and says Inner matrix dimensions must agree. Any insight into why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `.*` (element-wise multiplication), not `*` (matrix multiplication)

Comment: Yep. Very basic Matlab ;-)

Comment: Clearly the people who down-voted me thought so. Anyway, thanks a lot!